# How to get access to Immersive app's WPF interface by its HWND handle in Win32?

Tags: c++, wpf, xaml, winapi

I have a screen reader type Win32 application, written in C++. It may need to get UI layout (XAML markup) of an arbitrary Immersive (Metro) UWP app of a user's choosing. For that I can inject my DLL into the Immersive app and do the work from inside the context of the Immersive app. The next step though is obtaining the WPF interface for XAML extraction, using its Win32 window handle, or `HWND`. (I know that Microsoft implemented [interoperation between WPF and Win32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-and-win32-interoperation), so there must be a way.)

The question is how to obtain a pointer to the WPF interface by its window handle `HWND`? (Or using the window with the Win32 class name `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`.)

PS. I did some search and found similar interop projects ([ref0](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/08/02/dealing-with-hwnd-in-wpf/), [ref1](http://daniel-albuschat.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-net-and-wpf-in-win32-legacy.html), [ref2](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2010/04/mfc-and-wpf-interop.html)) but unfortunately they don't do exactly what I need.

Comment: Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow is UWP and not WPF.

Comment: Surely the system provides something equivalent to UI Automation, for accessibility